# Where to find the fares of the Rodalies de Catalunya outside of Barcelona?

Tags: trains, catalonia

I am looking to travel from Barcelona-Sants to *La Tor de Querol-Enveig*/*Latour-de-Carol* in France, by train

I know that I will take the *Rodalies de Catalunya*'s R3 line, which is part of [Barcelona's network](https://rodalies.gencat.cat/es/tarifes/servei_rodalia_barcelona/nomes_rodalies/).

I can find the [timetable](https://rodalies.gencat.cat/web/.content/02_Horaris/horaris/R3.pdf) for that service, but I can't find anywhere the fares for it.

The fares inside the 6 zones of Barcelona are findable, but outside those zones, I couldn't find either fares or how to get a ticket for my destination

Comment: Possibly I'm missing something but it I go to https://rodalies.gencat.cat/en/horaris/, select the starting point,end point and time, it gives me the services and then further down, under a Fares button you need to expand,the details of the fares. It suggest 12 Euro for a regional service. Not sure how you buy a ticket though

Comment: According to https://www.seat61.com/Spain.htm#London_to_Barcelona_by_overnight_couchette_train you pay cash on the train.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was already noted in a comment, for travel on Catalonia regional trains outside the Barcelona urban area, you can see the point-to-point fares by entering your origin and destination station on the [timetable page](https://rodalies.gencat.cat/en/horaris/) or on the [mobile application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cat.gencat.mobi.rodalies&hl=en&gl=US) and picking any train. The prices don't depend on the day or time. The current single fare is 12€. A return is twice the price as a single. You can buy a 10-trip ticket (“Bonotren”) for a significantly reduced price, and it can be used by multiple passengers at the same time, though it seems that this is being discontinued and may not be available anymore. There are [concessions](https://rodalies.gencat.cat/en/tarifes/servei_rodalia_barcelona/nomes_rodalies/#children) for elderly and families (children above 4 pay full price unless a family discount apply) but I don't think a non-resident can easily get them.

**You must buy a ticket before boarding the train.** [Barcelona Sants](https://www.barcelona-tourist-guide.com/en/transport/stations/estacio-sants/ticketing-barcelona-sants.html) is served by both RENFE (the national train operator) and Rodalies de Catalunya (the regional operator), you need to use an [orange Rodalies de Catalunya ticket machine](https://www.barcelona-tourist-guide.com/images/int/transport/stations/estacio-sants/L550/sants-station-barcelona-1047.jpg) or queue at the regional ticket window. You must buy the ticket on the day of travel.

If you board the train at a station without ticket sales, and only in that case, you can buy a ticket on board. Unless this has changed recently, Latour-de-Carol does not have Catalunya ticket sales, so when coming from France you'd buy the ticket from Latour-de-Carol to Barcelona on board the train. But from Barcelona, you must buy a ticket at the station.

Note that **tickets must be validated before travel** (similarly to e.g. France and Italy), although I'm not sure if that applies to single tickets — they may come pre-validated. In the main Barcelona station, you'll have to insert your ticket in the fare gates anyway, so you can't forget to validate.

Comment: Rodalies ticket machines are orange, (red+grey is the metro/tmb, if you're buying tickets by zone you could use either, but for destinations I think it would matter) and validation at stations in Barcelona happens when you use the ticket to pass through the gates to enter the platform, you can't forget/avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm it is still (August '23) how it works

There are no sales of Rodalies de Catalunya tickets in Latour de Carol, you just hop on it and wait for the inspector to come around and pay €12 pp. in cash in exchange for a ticket printed on a paper slip

[image]